# Access to framebuffer Cocos2d/3d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I am trying to combine the String Augmented Reality Framework with cocos as the 3d renderer.
In the setup I need to provide String with the OpenGL context and the framebuffer.

```
 stringOGL = [[StringOGL alloc] initWithDelegate: self context: myEAGLContext frameBuffer: myFrameBuffer leftHanded: NO];
```

I get the context like this:

```
 [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] context]
```

But how to get the frameBuffer?

Comment: Just found this link
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.1/_e_a_g_l_view_8h_source.html

It refers to a member variable called frameBuffer in the EAGLView.h (version 99.1), however in my Cocos2d version (1.0.1) this member variable is not available anymore. 

I guess it was removed somewhere along the line. Has access been moved somewhere else, or was it removed?